# Wishlist relationships in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Im building an app where Users have some sort of wishlist

a User can have only one wishlist, and can add existing Items to that wishlist
however the Items belong to other Users on the site

I need to be able to access the wishlist items through current_user.wishlist.items (im using Devise so current_user is available)

i though of adding a wishlist_id column to the items table, but that wouldnt work since items can belong to multiple wishlists.

this seems simple but im having a hard time visualizing the relationship or the migration im supposed to generate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_one :wishlist # or belongs_to :wishlist, it depends which you prefer

end

class Wishlist < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
  has_and_belongs_to_many :items

end
```

And of course:

```
./script/rails generate migration create_item_wishlists wishlist_id:integer item_id:integer
```

to create join table between items and wishlists.

*UPDATE*: To answer "frank blizzard" question in comment:

Let's say you have the same structure as in my answer (just change Item to Product or other model name), with HABTM relationship you just need to add new "item" to collection of "items", and then save wishlist:

```
@user.wishlist.items << item
@user.wishlist.save
```

You can make it method in user:

```
class User
  def add_to_wishlist(item)
    wishlist.items << item
  end
end
```

If you want to remove or modify collection of "items", just use any Ruby method from Array and then save wishlist, which will check differences for you and save only changes.

Comment: i generated a wishlist relation like the above in my rails app, but now I have no idea how I would go about adding a product_id to the user's wishlist... do you mind to share a thought if you have one ? thanks!

Comment: @frankblizzard See my answer, I just updated it with solution for your question.

Comment: Does there need to be a user_id column in the Wishlist table? The SQL that tries to run on user.wishlist.items uses user_id in the WHERE clause and thus errors on the missing column.

When I do have user_id in the Wishlists table, doing user.wishlist returns Nil. user.wishlist.items errors as an undefined method. Similar results when doing @user.wishlist.items << item.

Am I missing something?

Comment: @Danomite Yes, you need `user_id` in Wishlist model. I also forgot to include `belongs_to :user` in Wishlist model. Make sure that you have User model (with correct table), Wishlist model (with `user_id` column in table), Item model (no special columns here) and you created many-to-many join table between wishlist and item (it should create table named `items_wishlists`, my migration example could be wrong here, please verify generated migration before running it)

Comment: @MBO Great answer.Though I do have a question. Can you tell me why did you use "**has_and_belongs_to_many**" instead of "**has_many :through**"?

Comment: @RahulRoy I think the sole reason was if you need intermediate object. They both work almost the same. Sure, `has_many :through` is more popular and mostly better now (and keep in mind I answered this question 3 years ago), but if you don't really need intermediate object and your whole relation can be declared as "set of objects" (not even list, as we can't order them), then why would you need class for it? But when you need validations, ordering or other attributes, then it's no way around creating additional class and using `has_many :through`